# Is it possible to use the xcode time profiler to see traces from your own libraries? If not, are there any alternatives?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

All I can see when using this tool are system libraries. Is it not possible to delve into the underlying methods (i.e. my own) that are causing these to be slow?

For example in the below image:

[image]

I would like to see the methods being called by `cellForItemAtIndexPath` (i.e. my own) and hence find out what is causing lagginess in my collection view.

If not, are there any other tools that could perform this kind of analysis?

Comment: It should work. Do you have "Generate Debug Symbols" disabled for your app?

Answer (score 0):

You can view your own implementations in code. I do not believe it is possible to view system library calls. Run the instruments Timer Profile from Xcode, Command --> I.

In Timer Profile, select "Hide System Libraries"

In your call tree, find the method you want to investigate, right click on the method and select "Reveal in Xcode".